# How to create a link in Android Studio that allows jumping to a certain line

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

My project has got over 5000 lines, and I am looking for something like this:

[image]

Where I create a link, say with name, `[goTo]` which is clickable and when I click on it, it should direct me to the given line. Is there anything like that which exist in Android Studio?

Comment: I do the workaround using //TODO

Comment: There could be many `TODO`s in the app.

Comment: You can use favorite groups: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-your-project-favorites.html. Or create your own plug-in that will make these code links active.

Answer (score 0):

With Javadoc, instead of lines, you can jump to other methods. Ctrl+B in Windows/Linux and Command+B in Mac.

```
/**
 * go to [two]
 */
class one() {
}

class two() {

}
```

Comment: I wanted a line number, because `[]` is only possible with class name or maybe a method. Thanks for your efforts though.